# Why do people group rspec under test and development in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm generally clear on bundler Gemfile options, but I'm not sure why rspec (specifically, rspec-rails) should be in both test and development.

Here are my test groupings:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
  gem "capybara"
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'growl'
end
```

Does this look ok?

Comment: This also applies for other testing 'frameworks' such as `minitest`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I am quoting [the official documentation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#configure):

> Add rspec-rails to the :test and :development groups in the Gemfile:

```
group :test, :development do   
    gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.6" 
end
```

> It needs to be in the :development group to expose generators and rake
>   tasks without having to type RAILS_ENV=test.

Comment: Additionally, I always focus less on the idea of both test and development and more on the idea of not production. My personal feeling is that I want to be able use any of my gems in development for the reason Amokrane expressed above

Comment: Now it's rspec 3, the quoted explanation has been removed.

The expected official documentation quoted should be:
 https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/tree/2-9-maintenance